# building a jar library from a war project using maven?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar

We have a EAR project which has a WAR project. Maven is used, so pom.xml. As typical of any project, this project also contains a big feature (say Job Scheduling "JBS") among many other features. As it is planned to retire this whole project in the near future, it is discouraged heavily to spend much on working on this project (whether bugs or enhancements).

Therefore, for the sake of running the (JBS) feature as a separate application, the whole EAR project was duplicated (also to save time/cost). As a result, all the Java packages and classes (necessary for JBS project) were duplicated. In this situation, if we update one or more classes in the main project, this (JBS) feature project/application gets outdated (and needs update).

The fact is that this JBS feature project ONLY requires many packages of Java classes (from the main EAR-WAR project), and do not require 99% of the web modules and others. I am removing all the unnecessary things from JBS project. Then I would like to create a JAR library with all the java classes, so JBS project can have a dependency on this JAR.

I do not know if it is a good idea to separate these classes out of the main project (to create another Java project). I would like to continue to have these classes as part of the main project. Then, it will be good, as and when one or more of these classes are changed, a new version of the JAR will be generated (right away). And the JBS project would then make use of this updated JAR.

How can we accomplish this? I understand, through maven, we can do a build/package jar/war/ear on a project of that nature. I am not an expert with maven (and did not learn it systematically).

But, is there a way to create one or more JARs additionally from inside WAR pom.xml? In other words: I mean pom.xml of WAR will create a WAR. In addition to creating a WAR, can maven help create additional JAR? Or can maven create two packages out of one pom.xml?

Or should I create a separate module in the main project with all these packages/classes, and have its own pom.xml to generate the necessary JAR? For this, most probably I need to modify the structure of the main project. I would like to avoid this unless there is no way out.

Can you advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the best thing for you would be to create a multi-module project that both contains the JAR and the other project. This way, you can easily change/build them together, but you create separate artifacts.